# Unit testing with Authlogic in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, authlogic

Authlogic seems to be messing up my unit tests. When I try to run any unit test, I get:

```
authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:31:in `acts_as_authentic': You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic (StandardError)
```

It doesn't matter what my unit test is. Even if all my unit test file contains is `require 'test_helper'`, I still get the error. This, of course, tells me that the problem is probably in my `test/test_helper.rb` file.

Here's my `test/test_helper.rb` (based on the example [here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb)):

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'authlogic/test_case'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic
end
```

Is anybody else having this problem? I don't know what to do.

Comment: I get the same problem but in an engine using RSpec.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had namespaced models, e.g `Qwerty::User`, which where linked to non-namespaced tables, i.e `users`, not `qwerty_users`, and when I used the Rails generator to make a new model, e.g `Qwerty::Post` it created also created a `Qwerty` module which contained:

```
def self.table_name_prefix
 'qwerty_'
end
```

This was then making my `Qwerty::User` model look for `qwerty_users` which was wrong, hence the "You must establish a database connection" error. The table did not exist.

Most likely there are a number of ways to get this error, but I doubt any of them will directly relate to authlogic itself.