# Authlogic doesn't work with my Rails 3.2 app

Tags: passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm running Rails 3.2 and the latest version of Authlogic. When I run my app locally on my Mac, it works fine. When I try to run it on my production server (Ubuntu with Passenger/Apache), I get this:

```
You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the problem. I posted [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517887/unit-testing-with-authlogic-in-rails-3-2) earlier today before I realized that the problem was broader than I thought.

Comment: I used to be a big authlogic fan, and had many apps in the 2.x era using it (including adapters for LDPA, RPX etc). I've since upgraded most of these to 3.0.x and 3.2 but in the process decided that on the whole its better and easier to migrate to devise. It's easy, and the code is cleaner (generally owing to having been designed in the 3.0 era). This doesn't answer your question .. I just mention it so you keep it in mind if authlogic keeps biting back; switching to devise is not such a big deal, and it won't take you long at all to get the basics in place.

Comment: I ended up finally switching to Devise the other day. It was an astonishingly easy and painless switch.

Comment: This seems to be fixed. For now we need to use `gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git'` in the gemfile to pull from the master branch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Look at this snippet from Authlogic's `lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb`:

```
    private
      def db_setup?
        begin
          column_names
          true
        rescue Exception
          false
        end
      end
```

If `column_names` throws an error, `db_setup?` will return false. Look at this other function, also from `base.rb`:

```
    def acts_as_authentic(unsupported_options = nil, &block)
      # Stop all configuration if the DB is not set up
      raise StandardError.new("You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic") if !db_setup?

      raise ArgumentError.new("You are using the old v1.X.X configuration method for Authlogic. Instead of " +
        "passing a hash of configuration options to acts_as_authentic, pass a block: acts_as_authentic { |c| c.my_option = my_value }") if !unsupported_options.nil?

      yield self if block_given?
      acts_as_authentic_modules.each { |mod| include mod }
    end
```

If `db_setup?` returns false, Authlogic will throw an exception, **but not the same exception thrown by `column_names`**.

My problem was that `column_names` was throwing this exception:

```
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1106:in `async_exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

And the reason for THAT exception is that my user table is called `user`, not `users`, but Rails was not picking up on my `pluralize_table_names` setting properly. Once I fixed my `pluralize_table_names` problem (apparently the way this setting works has been changed in Rails 3.1), my Authlogic problem went away.

So if you're having this problem, you might want to try this:

- Clone the Authlogic repo to somewhere on your dev machine
- Change your Gemfile to use the local version of Authlogic (`'authlogic', :path => '/path/to/authlogic'`)
- Add a `column_names` call to `db_setup?` outside the `begin`/`rescue`/`end` clause
- See if you get a different, potentially more accurate and informative, error, like I did

Comment: What would be really nice, of course, is if Authlogic were aware of the possibility of this problem. I posted a new question asking how to detect this particular problem so I can apply a patch to Authlogic...assuming that's a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557860/how-do-i-catch-this-specific-error-in-rails#comment12115170_9557860

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this on my fork. Until Ben has time to merge the fix you can work around this using the fixed branch in your Gemfile;

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git@github.com:james2m/authlogic.git', :branch => 'fix-migrations'
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who might have come to this page looking for an answer.

One reason could be that your haven't created your test database.

Just run:

> $ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

Follow the open issue at https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/318 and +1 so the fix gets merged soon :)