# Rails Migration Error - relation 'users' does not exist ('"users"'::regclass) - (rails 3.2.6 / Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, authlogic, database-migration

Good afternoon,

I'm having serious troubles getting my database back up and running.  I dropped my tables earlier this week (wanted to rebuild) and am having all kinds of problems.

I have done the following:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error (will put full stack trace at the bottom):

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Authlogic is the issue here.  The only reason I was able to see this error (the real error) was because I hid the authlogic error:

```
You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic
```

As suggested in this post: [Stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518976/authlogic-doesnt-work-with-my-rails-3-2-app)

User migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string    :name,               :null => false
      t.string    :email,               :null => false
      t.string    :plan, :default => "basic"
      t.boolean   :verified, :default => false
      t.boolean   :admin, :default => false
      t.integer   :selected_portfolio_id
      t.datetime  :last_email_at
      t.hstore    :data

      t.string    :crypted_password,    :null => false
      t.string    :password_salt,       :null => false
      t.string    :persistence_token,   :null => false
      t.string    :perishable_token,    :null => false

      # magic fields (all optional, see Authlogic::Session::MagicColumns)
      t.integer   :login_count,         :null => false, :default => 0
      t.integer   :failed_login_count,  :null => false, :default => 0
      t.datetime  :last_request_at
      t.datetime  :current_login_at
      t.datetime  :last_login_at
      t.string    :current_login_ip
      t.string    :last_login_ip

      # optional, see Authlogic::Session::Params
      #t.string    :single_access_token, :null => false  
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
    add_index :users, ["persistence_token"], :name => "index_users_on_persistence_token", :unique => true
  end
end
```

Why is authlogic trying to load up on a database migration?  I'm assuming this has to be the problem.... Full stack trace:

```
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1151:in `async_exec'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1151:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:664:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.    rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:663:in `exec_query'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1276:in `column_definitions'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:859:in `columns'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in     `default'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in     `columns'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:248:in     `column_names'
/Users/brandon/Documents/authlogic/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:67:in `db_setup?'
/Users/brandon/Documents/authlogic/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:31:in `acts_as_authentic'
/Users/brandon/Dropbox/code/myapp/app/models/user_related/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
/Users/brandon/Dropbox/code/myapp/app/models/user_related/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in     `block in load_file'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in     `new_constants_in'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in     `load_file'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in     `require_or_load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in     `load_missing_constant'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in     `block in const_missing'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in     `const_missing'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in     `block in constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in     `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in     `constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.    rb:54:in `constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:189:in `block in     observe'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:189:in `collect!'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:189:in `observe'
/Users/brandon/Dropbox/code/myapp/app/models/user_related/user_observer.rb:2:in `<class:UserObserver>'
/Users/brandon/Dropbox/code/myapp/app/models/user_related/user_observer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in     `block in load_file'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in     `new_constants_in'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in     `load_file'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in     `require_or_load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in     `load_missing_constant'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in     `block in const_missing'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in     `const_missing'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in     `block in constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in     `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in     `constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.    rb:54:in `constantize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:86:in     `instantiate_observer'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:59:in `block in     instantiate_observers'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:59:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/observing.rb:59:in     `instantiate_observers'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2     levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in     `instance_eval'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in     `execute_hook'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in     `block in on_load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in     `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in     `on_load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <    class:Railtie>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in     `call'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in     `execute_hook'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in     `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in     `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in     `run_load_hooks'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <    module:Finisher>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in     run_initializers'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in     `method_missing'
/Users/brandon/Dropbox/code/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in     `require'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in     `block in require'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in     `load_dependency'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in     `require'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in     `require_environment!'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in     initialize_tasks'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

**UPDATE 1**

I was able to solve this problem by commenting out "acts as authentic", migrating the database, then reapplying.  While it is a bandaid, it doesn't seem right.  How can I properly fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this to get it to work:

```
Object.const_defined?("User")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the UserObserver is responsible for loading the user class, which in turn loads the AuthLogic code that generates the error.

Check if commenting out the observer configuration

```
config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
```

makes the problem disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try this out tonight and get back to you.  (P.S. If it works, will there be any easy fixes to the problem?  Or will I always have to create the users table prior to allowing the user observer be present in the application config?)

Comment: This works only if I also comment out a bunch of stuff around ActiveAdmin.  More stuff calling the user model I suppose.... This is still bothering me though.  Why is ActiveRecord all of a sudden not smart enough to ensure the user table is there before calling it in all of these locations?  I've been working on the codebase for some time, and only just started having issues!

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with what ActiveRecord is able to do. AR behaves the expected way, telling you that the model you're trying to work with is not set up right. The problem is that some things you use insist on loading the User model at the time the environment is loaded, which is a precondition for running migrations.

Comment: So if you were going to deploy this code with ActiveAdmin or a user observer in place, you would have to comment out the offending pieces, deploy, migrate, uncomment, redeploy?  Is this normal?

Comment: You could wrap the relevant code in a User.table_exists? condition, to exclude it if the table doesn't exist yet.