# Ruby on Rails Heroku App Crashing [ web.1 crashed ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have followed all of the [Heroku / Rails 3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) information for deploying and have done so successfully in the past as well. For some reason this dyno keeps crashing on deployment and I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Here is the logs...

```
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in '
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2013-08-08T07:14:53.597852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in '
    2013-08-08T07:14:54.816593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-08-08T07:14:54.832103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-08-08T07:15:24.152264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-08-08T07:15:24.302037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-08-08T07:15:26.500540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-08-08T07:15:26.585865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-08-08T07:15:52.251894+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2013-08-08T07:15:57.691573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 37681`
    2013-08-08T07:16:02.767322+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-08-08T07:16:02.767322+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-08-08T07:16:02.767322+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.583098+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.583098+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37681
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.583098+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.583098+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.583098+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/authlogic-3.1.3/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:31:in `acts_as_authentic': You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic (StandardError)
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:2:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `safe_constantize'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.584623+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in '
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in '
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in '
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2013-08-08T07:16:03.585581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `'
    2013-08-08T07:16:05.244491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-08-08T07:16:05.269665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-08-08T07:16:06.134395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-08-08T07:16:06.471391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=retreat-4025.herokuapp.com fwd="66.148.232.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: maybe it has to do something with your database connection. see: 2013-08-08T07:16:03.584336+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/authlogic-3.1.3/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:31:in `acts_as_authentic': You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic (StandardError)

Comment: Try removing `acts_as_authentic` from User model and see if error persists.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518976/authlogic-doesnt-work-with-my-rails-3-2-app The person there seems to have the same problem as you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was just a matter of creating / migrating the database.

```
heroku rake db:create
```

and

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Thanks everyone for your help!